# Manage session and cookies in user login using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session, cookies

I have one login application and here i need to use session and cookies using angular.js.I am explaining my code below.

> loginController.js:

```
var loginAdmin=angular.module('Channabasavashwara');
loginAdmin.controller('loginController',function($scope,$http,$location){
    $scope.user_name = ''; 
    $scope.user_pass = '';
    $scope.user_login=function(){
    if($scope.user_name==''){
        alert('user name filed should not keep blank');
    }else if($scope.user_pass==''){
        alert('password filed should not keep blank');
    }else{
        var userData={'user_name':$scope.user_name,'user_pass':$scope.user_pass};
        console.log('user',userData);
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "php/Login/login.php",
            data: userData,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function successCallback(response){
            console.log('response',response);
            alert(response.data['msg']);
            $location.path('dashboard');
        },function errorCallback(response) {
            alert(response.data['msg']);
        });
    }
    }
});
```

Here my requirement is when user will logged in successfully the session will store and at the time of logout it will move.Similarly cookies will store with some expiration time(`lets say 10 min`) after the time will expire it will logout automatically with one alert message.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Using angularjs for cookie required module to download and add into project which is [ngCookie](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies) with example at [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) but you can get and set cookie using basic javascript also.

Below is setCookie function which get `cookie name`, `cookie value` and number of days to expire cookie. You can **set cookie** when user logged in and **remove** it when logged out.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

Example for angularjs cookie

```
 angular.module('cookiesExample', ['ngCookies'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
  // Retrieving a cookie
  var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('myFavorite');
  // Setting a cookie
  $cookies.put('myFavorite', 'oatmeal');
}]);
```

Comment: @ Sarjan : i will use this and inform you later.